# Lazy loading images from album

Tags: react-native

I'm still new-ish to react-native and have run into a bit of a problem.
I'm trying to load images in a flat list using community/cameraroll": Version "^1.8.1".
The function "fAlbumImage" gets the first 100 in the album.
`

```
const IMAGE_FETCH_COUNT = 100
const fAlbumImage = async (group_name, nextAlbum) => {
  console.log("Album hit me")
  try {
    const albumImages = await CameraRoll.getPhotos({
      after: nextAlbum !== '' ? nextAlbum : undefined,
      first: IMAGE_FETCH_COUNT,
      assetType: 'Photos',
      groupTypes: 'All',
      groupName: group_name
    })
    return {
      images: albumImages.edges,
      pagingAlbum: {
        nextAlbum: albumImages.page_info.has_next_page
          ? albumImages.page_info.end_cursor
          : '',
      },
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("No images found in album")
  }

}
```

`Ideally, I would like to get the rest of the album, Am I doing this the right way`

```
const getAlbumLocalId = async (group_name) => {
    //gets 100 images that have the same group name as the one that has been pressed
    const { images: AlbumIm = [], paging = {} } = await fetchImages("", "", "", group_name)
    setNextAlbum(paging.nextAlbum)
    console.log("nextAlbum", nextAlbum)
    setLoading(false)
    //group name is the variable you create but is getting what is being passed
    setSelectedAlbumImages(selectedAlbumImages => {
      return photo.filter((obj) => obj.node.group_name == group_name).map((obj) => {
        return obj
      })
    })
    setPhoto([...AlbumIm])
    setSelectedAlbumImages([...AlbumIm])
    setPhotoInAlbum(true)
    setLocalCoverImages(true)
  }
```

`
Any help will be appreacted :) many thanks

I want to keep getting 100 images at a time until we have received all the images in the album for optimized loading.

Answer (score -1):

Why go for lazy loading photos at all? Lazy Loading defers the loading of an photo that is no longer wished on the web page immediately. An image, no longer seen to the person when the web page loads, is loaded later when the person scrolls and the picture absolutely turns into visible.

Comment: I understand, but I'm trying to make a gallery app. When I tried to pull all the images, the scrolling was slow, when I scrolled past 500 images some of them are invisible and can't be displayed. What would you suggest

Comment: this is not an answer nor a solution, this is an argument with the OP question

Comment: this is not an answer, please try to supply an answer or just comment on the question instead